# how can I return the POST value and print on the web site?(wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, web

this is the page-user-form.php

```html
            <form action="<?php echo esc_attr( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" method="POST" id="userForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="user_form2">
    <p><label for="form-title">pass name:
            <input type="text" name="pass" id="form-title">
    </label></p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

this is functions.php file in wordpress

```html
function user_form() {
  check_admin_referer( 'user_form2' );
  global $wpdb, $inputValue;
  $inputValue = $_POST['pass'];
  $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_kboard_board_content WHERE title = %s", $inputValue);
  $query_result = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    if($inputValue){
    wp_redirect( esc_url( home_url( '/wordpress/result/' )));
    exit;
}
return $query_result;
}
//user_form();
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_user_form2', 'user_form' );
add_action( 'admin_post_user_form2', 'user_form' );


add_shortcode('my_db_print','my_db_print_function');
function my_db_print_function(){
ob_start();
$results =  user_form();
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>title</th><th>content</th><th>date</th><th>category1</th></tr>";
foreach ( $results as $result ) 
{
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>".$result->title."</td>";
echo"<td>".$result->content."</td>";
echo"<td>".$result->date."</td>";
echo"<td>".$result->category1."</td>";
echo"<tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
return ob_get_clean(); */
}
```

I want to output specific db data(mysql) based on the value entered by the user.($_POST['pass'])
but the result is NULL even if there have data.

I don't know which part is wrong. Someone please help me!!!

Comment: What does it mean exactly the result is NULL? Do you see the table defined in `my_db_print_function` when you include the shortcode to your post? Maybe include the generated code in your question as well wo make it easier to understand for us whats happening.

Comment: When the user enters a value in the input field, the input value enters the sql statement, and the specific table contents should be displayed, but result didn't displayed. I think  function user_form() in functions.php doesn't get the input values from the page-user-form.php, can you see if there's a problem?
Yes I can see the table defined in my_db_print_function.

Comment: It's hard to understand what should happen, because the overall context is missing, I can see two different case where `user_form` gets called. a) when the form `#userForm` get actually submitted. The `add_action`-lines should should trigger it then. It returns bare data, but does not generate any output. Completely unrelated it gets called from `my_db_print_function` wich is a shortcode-resolver. That means if, in a post there is a shortcode `[my_db_print]` the content gets replaced by the result of the function. ...

Comment: But at this point of displaying the post is there anything in `$_POST` - most likely not; except the resulting page of the submitted `#userForm` is displaying the post. But if you look at the post later `$_POST` will be empty. In short: I guess (but cannot know for sure) there is a conceptual bug. Try to echo out something in `user_form`, maybe even call `my_db_print_function` from there instead of the otherway round. That could lead you to the right steps maybe. An have a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_action/

Comment: Oh, I understand what you said. Finally, I solved the problem. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Great! I made an answer out of the comments, maybe you may mark it as correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made an answer out of my comment, since it seemed to be the correct solution:

I can see two different case where user_form gets called.

a) when the form #userForm get actually submitted. The add_action-lines should should trigger it then. It returns bare data, but does not generate any output. Have a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_action/.

b) Completely unrelated it gets called from my_db_print_function which is a shortcode-resolver. That means if, in a post there is a shortcode `[my_db_print]` the content gets replaced by the result of the function.

But at this point of displaying the post is there anything in `$_POST`? Most likely not; except the resulting page of the submitted `#userForm` is displaying the post. But if you look at the post later, `$_POST` will be empty. In short: There is a conceptual bug. Call `my_db_print_function` from there instead of the other way round.